# if duplicate update, else add records (from excel to access)

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have a command button in excel to insert the records to access table. Here's my vba code.

```
Option Explicit

Sub AddRecordsIntoAccessTable()

    Dim accessFile  As String
    Dim accessTable As String
    Dim sht         As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow     As Long
    Dim lastColumn  As Integer
    Dim con         As Object
    Dim rs          As Object
    Dim sql         As String
    Dim i           As Long
    Dim j           As Integer
            
    'Disable the screen flickering.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    'Specify the file path of the accdb file. You can also use the full path of the file like this:
    'AccessFile = "C:\Users\Christos\Desktop\Sample.accdb"
    accessFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Database daily activity.accdb"
         
    'Ensure that the Access file exists.
    If FileExists(accessFile) = False Then
        MsgBox "The Access file doesn't exist!", vbCritical, "Invalid Access file path"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'Set the name of the table you want to add the data.
    accessTable = "DAILY_ACTIVITY"
                
    'Set the worksheet that contains the data.
    On Error Resume Next
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Daily Activity")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "The given worksheet does not exist!", vbExclamation, "Invalid Sheet Name"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Err.Clear
        
    'Find the last row and last column in the given worksheet.
    With sht
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        lastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With
    
    'Check if there are data in the worksheet.
    If lastRow < 2 Or lastColumn < 1 Then
        MsgBox "There are no data in the given worksheet!", vbCritical, "Empty Data"
        Exit Sub
    End If
        
    'Create the ADODB connection object.
    Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
    
    'Check if the object was created.
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "The connection was not created!", vbCritical, "Connection Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Err.Clear
    
    'Open the connection.
    con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & accessFile
    
    'Create the SQL statement to retrieve the table data (the entire table).
    sql = "SELECT * FROM " & accessTable
    
    'Create the ADODB recordset object.
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    
    'Check if the object was created.
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set rs = Nothing
        Set con = Nothing
        MsgBox "The recordset was not created!", vbCritical, "Recordset Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Err.Clear
             
    'Set the necessary recordset properties.
    rs.CursorType = 1   'adOpenKeyset on early binding
    rs.LockType = 3     'adLockOptimistic on early binding
        
    'Open the recordset.
    rs.Open sql, con
    
    'Add the records from Excel to Access by looping through the rows and columns of the given worksheet.
    'Here the headers are in the row 1 and they are identical to the Access table headers.
    'This is the reason why, for example, there are no spaces in the headers of the sample worksheet.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    On Error GoTo 0
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        rs.AddNew
        For j = 1 To lastColumn
            'This is how it will look like the first time (i = 2, j = 1):
            rs(sht.Cells(1, j).Value) = sht.Cells(i, j).Value
        Next j
        rs.Update
    Next i
        
    'Close the recordet and the connection.
    rs.Close
    con.Close
    
    'Release the objects.
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set con = Nothing
    
    'Re-enable the screen.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    'Inform the user that the macro was executed successfully.
    MsgBox lastRow - 1 & " rows were successfully added into the '" & accessTable & "' table!", vbInformation, "Done"
    
End Sub

Function FileExists(FilePath As String) As Boolean
 
    '--------------------------------------------------
    'Checks if a file exists (using the Dir function).
    '--------------------------------------------------
 
    On Error Resume Next
    If Len(FilePath) > 0 Then
        If Not Dir(FilePath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then FileExists = True
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
 
End Function
```

This code can only add new records, and it will be error if there is duplicate.

How do I fix the code with the condition:

1. Update existing access table for the records that is duplicate.
2. Add the records that is non duplicate

Comment: Why is Excel involved? Excel as user interface for database really makes life difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Could do a Find on recordset to determine if data already exists. If it does, focus will be on that record, otherwise pointer will be at recordset EOF.

```
For i = 2 To lastRow
    rs.Find "some field=" & cell reference, , , 1
    If rs.EOF Then
        rs.AddNew
    Else
        rs.Edit
    End If
    For j = 1 To lastColumn
        'This is how it will look like the first time (i = 2, j = 1):
        rs(sht.Cells(1, j).Value) = sht.Cells(i, j).Value
    Next j
    rs.Update
Next i
```